# Efficiently plot large coastline file with gnuplot

Tags: performance, gnuplot

I have a large data file, coastlines.csv, which represents the coastlines of the world, in this format

```
-4.94237 55.725449
-4.941922 55.725585
....
```

where each row represents a point, the first entry its the longitude, the second one is the latitude, both in degrees. The file has ~ 3 x 10^6 lines, and weighs ~ 700 MB.

Plotting this file with gnuplot

```
plot 'coastlines.csv'
```

takes some time, which is understandable. When I make the plot above and then click on it, draw a square with the mouse and zoom to replot a small region of the world only, the new plot takes the same amount of time as the full one.

I have the impression that gnuplot is checking all the points in the file again, because it does not know which ones will fall within the new plotting window.

Is there a way to speed up this replot?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered saving it as a PNG file so you can zoom in and out with an image viewer?

Comment: If you want to plot only a subset of the original entries based on their line number, you can also use the `every` keyword. If you plot only every nth line, you can gain some speed.

Comment: How is the data organized? Just points on the coast lines? Are they maybe separated/clustered by country within the large file? What about different continents or islands? Are they separated by one or two empty lines?